# piece of redux state changes to null when I try to print it in a component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to show a user's information on a dashboard component, just with a simple:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.authReducer.user
})
```

When I login or register the appropriate actions are called as well as the USER_LOADED action; all the user information is shown in redux-logger with the user object showing "name", "id" and other information. However, when I try to post the user name with

```
const Dashboard = ({ user, isAuthenticated }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {user.name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

everything turns to null, including the isAuthenticated value (which was initially set to true after successful login.) **I can use JSON.stringify on the user object and it shows their values fine**, but if I try to use JSON.stringify with user.name, I get the same error shown below where the value becomes null.
Why would me trying to list the user redux state cause it's value to become null?
I'm using redux-persist (I don't know if this has anything to do with it)

**Dashboard.js (component):**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Dashboard = ({ user, isAuthenticated, token }) => {
  return (
    <div>
     {user.name}
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.authReducer.user
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

**authReducer.js:**

```
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT,
  ACCOUNT_DELETED
} from '../../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  loading: true,
  user: null
}

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case USER_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
        user: payload
      }
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false
      }

    case REGISTER_FAIL:
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT:
    case ACCOUNT_DELETED:
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: false
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default authReducer;
```

**auth (actions):**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';

import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT,
  CLEAR_PROFILE
} from './types';

import setAuthToken from '../utils/setAuthToken';

//LOAD USER
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
  if (localStorage.token) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  }

  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data
    })
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR
    })
  }
}

//Register user
export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);

    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(loadUser());

  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;
    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_FAIL
    })
  }
}

//Login user
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/auth', body, config);

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(loadUser());
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;
    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL
    })
  }
}

//Logout clear profile
export const logout = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: CLEAR_PROFILE
  });
  dispatch({
    type: LOGOUT
  });

}
```

**auth.js (route that authenticates user/gets token):**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const User = require('../../models/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('config');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

//@route GET api/auth
//@desc Test route
//@access Public
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});

//@route POST api/auth
//@desc Authenticate user and get token
//@access Public
router.post('/', [
  check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
  check('password', 'Password is required').exists()
], async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Invalid credentials' }] })
    }


    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Invalid credentials' }] });
    }

    const payload = {
      user: {
        id: user.id
      }
    }
    jwt.sign(payload,
      config.get('jwtSecret'),
      { expiresIn: 360000 },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.json({ token })
      });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }


});

module.exports = router;
```

**homepage redux values:**
[image]

**I click on dashboard and it looks like store is reset:**
[image]
I get this error upon trying to display any piece of the user object :
[image]

Comment: please share whole bunch of code. @connect, reducer, and so on. it is hard to figure out problem from pieces.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov I've added the appropriate reducer, component, actions file, and route file. Please let me know if I'm missing anything and thank you for your correction.

Comment: user is null in `intialState`. So the initial render fails with NPE. Maybe some guard is needed inside `Dashboard` component?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov It's like the store resets on navigating to dashboard (a protected route.) I've included two pictures that show the store of the homepage (having a user object) and after navigating to Dashboard (it resets the store, it looks like.) Is it maybe redux persist rehydrating to initial state?

Comment: Update, when I login, it forwards properly to the dashboard where the user name is shown. If I refresh the page however, I still have the token in the Redux state, but user and isAuthenticated are set to null with the action PERSIST and REHYDRATE both being called. The Auth reducer is included in the persist store, so I'm not sure why it's resetting. Other values are persisted through refresh so it's quite odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answered** I didn't have my auth reducer in the whitelist of my persistConfig object in my root reducer. The data wasn't persisting as it wasn't listed to persist *facepalm*